# How to remove tinyMCE button from specific user role wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I found the answer from [Nathan Powell](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199918/remove-tinymce-from-admin-and-replace-with-textarea/199919#199919) but I can not apply this function to a specific user role. I want this function applies only for user "author" role.

I've been using :

```
if ( !current_user_can( 'author' )):
```

and I'm wondering how to place it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
function wpse_199918_wp_editor_settings( $settings, $editor_id ) {
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

      if ( $current_user->roles[0] === 'author' ) {

          $settings['tinymce']   = false;
          $settings['quicktags'] = false;
          $settings['media_buttons'] = false;
      }

      return $settings;
      }

     add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'wpse_199918_wp_editor_settings', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Yes, it is **already working**. You're so genius, thanks a lot +1 @AshPatel

Comment: @Fitri Zulkarnain: wel come :)